# Plugin reload causes clients to disconnect with an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, minecraft

**General Info**
I'm working on a chat plugin for Spigot (Minecraft server). The idea is to create a chatsystem that allows the use of working chat tabs:

[image: Example of Minecraft chat plugin]

In order to accomplish this, I have to use NMS (ProtocolLib) because Minecraft uses 3 types of messages in chat:

1. Chat messages
2. System messages
3. Game info messages

Chat messages are easily accessible, but the other 2 are not. If I don't catch those messages, they push the tabs menu up instead of ending up in their own chat channel.

**The problem**
The code (below) I'm using to catch these messages is causing the following exception in connected Minecraft clients and disconnects them upon an ingame plugin reload through `/reload`:

> DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0)
>   + length(1) exceeds writerIndex(0) UnpooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0/0, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 2, widx:
>   6, cap: 16384)) @ io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder:98

**Relevant code**

```
private void initPacketListener(){
    protocolManager.addPacketListener(new PacketAdapter(this, ListenerPriority.NORMAL, new PacketType[] { PacketType.Play.Server.CHAT })
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {

            if ((event.getPacketType() == PacketType.Play.Server.CHAT)){
                PacketContainer packet = event.getPacket();
                Player player = event.getPlayer();
                String message = "";

                try {
                    String jsonMessage = event.getPacket().getChatComponents().getValues().get(0).getJson();

                    if (jsonMessage!=null&&!jsonMessage.isEmpty()) {
                        message = jsonToString(jsonMessage);

                        if (message.isEmpty()) return;

                        Subscriber subscriber = UMM.plugin.getSubscribers().get(player.getUniqueId());
                        String uuid = player.getUniqueId().toString();
                        Channel messageChannel = UMM.serverChannels.get(uuid);
                        messageChannel.addMessage(message);
                        ChatListener cl = new ChatListener(UMM.plugin);

                        cl.notifyChanges(messageChannel);
                        event.setCancelled(true);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not a system msg");
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e){
                    System.out.println("UMM Packet Error:" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**What I've tried myself to solve the issue**
I asked some other devs about the problem and was told:

> Make sure that the size/length of event.getPacket().getChatComponents().getValues() is greater than 0 before making the #get call.

So I tried this:

```
List<WrappedChatComponent> wrap = event.getPacket().getChatComponents().getValues();

if(wrap.size() > 0) {
    if ((event.getPacketType() == PacketType.Play.Server.CHAT)){
        ...
    }
}
```

But it had no effect at all. They were unable to help me any further so I hope someone else might know what's going on and how I can solve the problem.

**Update**
Even after reducing the code to just this, the problem still persists:

```
private void initPacketListener(){
        protocolManager.addPacketListener(new PacketAdapter(this, ListenerPriority.NORMAL, new PacketType[] { PacketType.Play.Server.CHAT })
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {
            }
    });
}
```

A "temporary" solution to the problem is using a `BukkitRunnable` to call the method 1 tick after the server is done reloading. The only down side to this is that any messages appearing before the first tick are pushing the tabs menu up. The plugin fixes this upon the next message event.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `/reload` command, see more here for example : https://madelinemiller.dev/blog/problem-with-reload/.

You can implement a reload command in your plugin that does what you want if you need it. Maybe your issue could be gone with an internal reload command because it might be a issue with `/reload` command.

Comment: It's not about what I do. It's about what the users of the plugin I'm developing do. I have no need for users to reload this plugin. I'm just trying to keep it working in case they do. Therefor this is not a solution to the problem. This is like saying: There's a bug / issue with my program, but instead of fixing it, I'm just telling you not to use build-in server features.